# How to implement an else clause in POSIX bc?

Tags: bc

[POSIX bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_chapter/bc_toc.html) has neither an `else` clause nor boolean operators. Is there any simple way to do simulate an `else` clause?

Answer (score 1):

Use a second `if` statement. The code

```
if (expression) {
   statement1
} else {
   statement2
}
```

in GNU `bc` does the same as

```
if (expression) {
   statement1
} 
if (expression == 0) {
   statement2
}
```

in POSIX `bc`.